# Trying to get Code::Blocks working on Mac, running Lion. Can't get the compiler set up properly

Tags: xcode, g++, osx-lion, codeblocks

First off, sorry if this is a stupid question. I installed code::blocks to try and get to know the program and start working on teaching myself c++. I have a MacBook Pro with OS 10.7.3. I ave code::blocks 10.05. When I try to build a "Hello world" nothing happens. Based on some googling I've figured out that it's because code::blocks doesn't know where to find the debugger/compiler. Further googling yielded me [this page](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler#Mac_OS_X) which tells me to install Xcode and to fix some things in the code::blocks settings. However, this wiki obviously has not been updated since Apple went to the App store, because the file paths it gives for the compiler do not exist (there is no /Developer/* even after installing Xcode). Xcode 4.3.2 was already installed when I installed code::blocks and code::blocks "auto-detected" several compilers. They did not work. If anyone knows where Xcode hides its compilers now that Apple has moved to the app store, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides Xcode the app, you need to install the "command line tools", which allow you to call the compilers from the command line.

Go to this page: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php

And look under "Looking for additional developer tools".  It'll require you to log in with your Apple developer ID (which is free to get if you haven't already paid the $99 for the program membership). Once you are in, the package you want to install next is "Command Line Tools for Xcode - Late March 2012" (or whatever the latest one listed there is).

Comment: Perfect! That did it. Now, do I need to do any of the compiler search directory, linker search directory, or additional compiler flags?

Comment: It's worked so far, so I suppose not. I updated the code::blocks wiki to make it a bit more obvious what is needed so hopefully this question won't get asked again.